# How can you force an ASP.Net GridView to display an EmptyDataTemplate given there's only a single data record with all blanks?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My stored procedure, instead of returning zero rows, returns one with most of the columns NULL. When my .Net code sees such data, I wish to force it to display the EmptyDataTemplate. How?

Comment: It should not be **GridView**'s responsibility. Instead, data should be filtered at **Data Layer** or the worst case **Business Logic Layer**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Win,

In the LinqDataSource Selecting event handler I check if the data source has a size of one and has a null value for one of the key fields and then I pass in this to the LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs' Result:

```
using (var dataContext = new WebDataContext())
{
  var report = from row in dataContext.GetReport()
  select new Report()
  {
    AccountCode = row.AccountCode //,
   //...
  }
}

if (report.Count() == 1 && report.ToList()[0].AccountCode == null)
{
  var emptyReport = report.ToList();
  report.Clear();

  e.Result = emptyReport;
}
else
{
//...
  e.Result = matrixReport;
//...
}
```